# how to connect IBM cloudant database to python app code already on IBM cloud(cloud foundary)?

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-cloud-functions

I am using Django to create python based web application, and deployed it on IBM Cloud Foundry service, now I want to connect it with IBM cloudant to store all recorded query in cloudant databse using python.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will be useful for you and the community. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use the https://pypi.org/project/ibmcloudant/ package. You can find documentation on [IBM Cloud Docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant?code=python).

On IBM Cloud there are still many examples using [the cloudant library](https://pypi.org/project/cloudant/), but it is now deprecated and will be end-of-life on Dec 31 2021.

You see that it's based on couchdb, and as you are looking for a Django database - https://pypi.org/project/django-couchdb-storage/